# Magento 1.9 redirect customer after registration

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I would like to redirect all customers to a custom page after successful registration in Magento 1.9.

I have tried many things. Firstly, I am successfully overriding the core customer account controller.

I have attempted to customize the following actions:

- createPostAction
- _successProcessRegistration
- _welcomeCustomer

By trying to set redirect url or by setting BeforeAuthUrl

```
    //$successUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true));
    $successUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/success');
    $this->_getSession()->setBeforeAuthUrl('http://test.local/customer/account/success/');
    if ($this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl()) {
        $successUrl = $this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);
    }
    return $successUrl;
```

Please note at this point, $successUrl is correct when it returns here. I see there are some post Dispatch methods that I am assuming are destorying this url and always returning to customer/account/index.

I have read several posts on this topic and cannot find a definitive answer that solves this question.

I have even set hidden form element 'success_url' in attempts to follow steps presented elsewhere as solutions to this.

What is the full, correct process that one needs to follow in order to be able to show a one time registration success page?

Comment: you want this only during customer regisration?

Comment: Yes please, only during registration.

Comment: Doesnt work for me! about to try on standard 1.9 and will get back!

Comment: Wait give u total solution. This event occur immediat eafter customer successfully register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do `this for customer successfully then you can do this using` **event observer**

after customer `successfully magento trigger` an event `customer_register_success`

This call an observer which will reequestion to custtom page

```
  Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirct($Yourdreicurll);
```

Details:

**Step1:**
create  `config.xml` is `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/` - See more at: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#sthash.JSktrUD0.dpuf
and it code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
            </custommodule>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
      <events>
          <customer_register_success>
        <observers>
          <notify_user>
            <class>custommodule/observer</class>
            <method>myredirection</method>
          </notify_user>
        </observers>
          </customer_register_success>     
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Step2:**

create module control file Module name as  Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/

it code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step3:**

Create observer.php at Amit>Custommodule>Model

code is

```
 <?php
    class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Observer {
        public function myredirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();

        $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

         $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args

            $url = 'http://www.example.com/';
            $response1->setRedirect($url);
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();

        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I would say that "customer_register_success" event is not total end of registration. There is another method _successProcessRegistration() that follows immediately after that event and by redirecting in the observer as proposed it will not be executed. I would suggest to set the redirect value in the observer to redirect at the very end of the entire registration process: 
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('some/path/index', array('_secure' => true)));

Comment: iam also getting same issue ,how to fix this issue @KaushalSuthar

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread maybe this will help someone else out trying to accomplish the same thing. You can set the redirect URL in the register.phtml template directly without having to modify controllers or create a module. You can set success and error URLs with hidden inputs like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="my-custom-success-url.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="my-custom-error-url.html" />
```

I used this to redirect the user back to where they entered the login/register process like this:

```
<?php $ref = $this->getRequest()->getParam('referer');?>
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo !empty($ref)?Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($ref):$this->getSuccessUrl(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this in right way, this is the best way to redirect customer to custom URL.

1. Go to customer accountcontroller find _welcomeCustomer method.
2. Search for `$successUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true));` replace this code with your custom URL `$successUrl = $this->_getUrl('costomURL', array('_secure' => true));`

It works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to test this now.

Comment: Works perfectly on clean magento installation. testing a little more before I mark as correct.

Comment: Do not override the Magento source files, because these sort of modifications will disappear by next update.